# How can I understand the multiclass verison of "shattering" intuitively?

Tags: machine-learning, pac-learning

I'm learning machine learning. VC dimension is a good way to measure the complexity of hypothesis class for binary classifier and has a very good intuitive explanation from shattering.

I know that both dimensions are based on the "shattering" concept.

When we discuss VC-dimension, shattering means $H$ have all the behaviors on a set of size less than $VCdim(H)$. That is:

Let $C=(c_1,\dots,c_d)$ be a shattered set by $H$.
Denote the restriction of $H$ to $C$ by $H_c$.
$$H_c = \{(h(c_1),\dots,h(c_d)):h\in H\}$$
Then $$|H_c| = 2^d$$
However, according to the definition of shattering on **Page 403** of the book [**"Understanding Machine Learning: from theory to algorithms"**](https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/%7Eshais/UnderstandingMachineLearning/understanding-machine-learning-theory-algorithms.pdf)(You can click the link to download the book.), the multiclass version of "shattering" is as follows:

> We say a that a set $C\subset X$ is shattered by $H$ if there exist 2 functions $f_0$, $f_1: C\to [k]$ such that
>
> - for every $x\in C$, $f_0(x) \ne f_1(x)$.
> - for every $B\subset C$, there exists a function $h\in H$ such that
>
> $$\forall x\in B, h(x)=f_0(x)\ and\ \forall x\in C \backslash B, h(x) = f_1(x)$$

Here, $H$ does not have all the behaviors on a set of size less than the Nagarajan dimension. That is,

$$|H_c| \ne k^d$$ when $k>2$.

How do you understand the definition of the multiclass version of shattering, especially this point?

Comment: Cross site post: https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/16619/4446

Answer (score 1):

## Original question:

This is actually fairly straightforward if you translate from math to human.

You have a set, i.e. a grab-bag of possible inputs, called $C$, and a function $h(x)$ that can work on all the things in it.

If you imagine the C is a bag of marbles, some of them are Blue, some are other Colors.

If you separated them, the new bag with only Blues will be a new bag `B`, and you'll be left with the other bag C, except *without* all the Blues, so we'll call it `C\B`.

---

**If C is shattered by h**, the definition simply explains what $h(x)$ does. It grabs a random marble from the bag, if it's Blue it feeds them to function $f1(x)$, otherwise it feeds them to function $f2(x)$, and spits out whatever those functions would.

There's an additional constraint, which is that $f_1$ must, in practice, be different from $f_2$.

In practice meaning something like:

$$f_1 := 2x+2$$

$$f_2 := 0.5*(4x+4)$$

doesn't count, as it's blatantly cheating.

They need to be able to use the same **input** to produce a *different* **output**.

You can extend it to any number of specific 'colors': partition the input space into some non-overlapping chunks, pick a *unique* function $F_n(x)$ for each chunk, and let $h(x)$ dispatch the actual computation to one of the $F(x)$es based on which chunk your x is in.

---

## **Re: edited part**:

I'll start with a caveat that the 'behavior' here seems a little under-defined for my tastes, so I may be misunderstanding something.

In the binary case, since the sum of probabilities of all the options is 1, any nonempty subset of inputs from C to h assigns between 0 and 1 of the total probability to one class, and the rest to the other.

So, even if $f2(x)$ doesn't ostensively work for some specific x, you can infer what it 'should' output by simply calculating $1-f1(x)$, or vice versa.

Note that you only ever need two functions in this definition. If you want to support, say, three, you can rewrite $f2(x)$ as $g2(x) := ({f_2}_a(x)$ if something else ${f_2}_b(x))$, and so on, so the definition still holds.

---

## **Re: edited^2:**

Oh dear. This is a *long* story.

The cardinality of H is defined here as the count of all possible function outputs for all included inputs. They don't need to be *distinct* (i.e. if $h(c_1) = h(c_7) = h(c_{124})$ all three are counted as three different items).

If we had just ***one*** class, there's only one possible output per all inputs,  $p(k_1) = 1$. That means the cardinality of $H$ grows linearly with the number of inputs in $C$.

With **two** classes, the outputs are bounded between zero and one - simply by the definition of probability. Furthermore, they are complementary: $p(k_2|x) = 1 - p(k_1|x)$, so we only need to know one to infer the other.

If you took reals as your $C$, you can plot some values of $p(k_1)$ on the x-axis, and the values of $p(k_2)$ that satisfy this condition on the y axis of a 2D plot. An interesting feature of that is that if you look at these pairs and plot enough of them, you get a 45-degree slope from $(0,1)$ to $(1,0)$, forming a **right triangle** with the X & Y axes.

By simple application of Pythagoras, we can find the exact length of that slope, which corresponds to the number of *all valid **single-class outputs*** = $\sqrt{1^2+1^2} = \sqrt 2$.

Now, that's for one half of the pair. We have two. Since we're operating on reals, picking one for the value of $p(k_1)$ doesn't really shrink the space of options for $p(k_2)$, so we can pretend they're independent samples with replacement. Therefore, the total number of possible outcomes for all classes a single input in C is:

$$|H_x| = {\sqrt 2}^2 = 2$$

Rinse and repeat for N inputs in C, each one expands the space by a factor of 2, so 
$$|H_c| = {({\sqrt 2}^2)}^n = 2^n$$

Now, if you add a ***third*** class... things get messy. Now $p(k_1) + p(k_2) + p(k_3) = 1$. Now instead of a 1D slope in a 2D space, you need to find a 2D area in a 3D space; it's a triangle anchored at $(1,0,0); (0,1,0); (0,0,1)$.

I'll... leave you to it, okay? There's a reason I'm not on the GeometryExchange, and this answer is long enough as-is.

Again, take the answer and raise it to the Nth power to get the actual cardinality over $C_N$. Similarly, for additional classes, you get higher-dimensional analogues (hyperplanes) of valid outputs.

Comment: Thank you a lot and I really appreciate your help. I have another puzzle. When we discuss shattering for binary hypothesis class, the hypothesis class have all the behaviors on a set of  size less than or equal to the VC dimension of the hypothesis class. However, in the definition of shattering for multi-class version, it is not the case. How do you understand this aspect?

Comment: Thanks. I'm still puzzled by the question. And I have added what the "behavior" means. I will be looking forward to your answer.

Comment: Well, the answer to that turned out to be longer than the original answer and the first edit, but it's here now.

Comment: Thank you. But I guess that you may misunderstand something. In particular, in binary classification, either $h(x)$ = 1 or $h(x)=0$, $h(x)$ never be a real number.

Comment: That's not specified anywhere in the question, and seems like a bit of a needless restriction for a classifier. But it doesn't matter; your definition is simply a limiting case. *Any* problem where $R$ independent variables sum to 1 is - specifically, any such $h(x)$ is Dirichlet-distributed, and the cardinality of $H$ is equal to $n$ times the entropy of Dirichlet (too long to write out here).